# "It was Ken's birthday yesterday"/"There was Ken's birthday yesterday"

Tags: grammar, dates, dummy-pronouns

I was doing exercises from Murphy's textbook and came across the following sentence:

> It was Ken's birthday yesterday. We had a party.

I should have changed 'it' to 'there' where it was necessary, so I replaced it to 'There was Ken's birthday.." because the grammar says that

> We use there ... when we talk about something for the first time, to
> say that it exists

But the right answer was that this sentence was OK with 'It' at the beginning. I was surprised, because there hasn't been any mention about Ken's birthday before and they say about it for the first time. So why can't we put 'There' instead?

Comment: What your grammar book says about _there_ is true when we are talking about a thing, person or animal - for example 'there is a cat in the garden'. However, we use _it_ when we are talking about a date - 'It is Saturday tomorrow' - 'It is my birthday next week'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use normally use the dummy subject 'it' if we are simply saying a particular day, month, or year had, has, or will have some characteristic:

> It was my birthday yesterday.
>
> It is Tuesday today.
>
> It will be Christmas two weeks from today.
>
> It is June next month.

You could use 'there is/was/will be' to talk about the occurence of something, e.g. 'there was Ken's birthday yesterday, and there will be Mary's next week'.